# Create a custom box with an arrow underneath using swift programatic ui

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am a junior swiftui developer, i am working on a project that require me to use UIKit in some of its part.

i want to achieve a view similar to the attached image which is an example of Waze Advertisment box:

[image]

after checking MapBox API and looking at some of the example i learned that if i want to achieve this i should use swift programatic ui which i am not that familiar with, in the example they have provided the following view:

[image]

and the way they have created it was as follow:

```
final class AdvertismentAnnotationView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: AdvertismentAnnotationViewDelegate?

    //Passing this model to get the data and display it
    var advertismentModel: AdvertismentModel
    
    var selected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            selectButton.setTitle(selected ? "Deselect" : "Select", for: .normal)
        }
    }
    var title: String? {
        get { centerLabel.text }
        set { centerLabel.text = newValue }
    }
    lazy var centerLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
    }()
    lazy var closeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    lazy var selectButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.setTitle("Select", for: .normal)
        return button
    }()
    
    //MARK: This is what i have added
    //and image that will later fetch the image from advertisment.imageURL
    lazy var adImage: UIImage = {
        return UIImage()
    }()
    
   
    
    //MARK: Lifecycle
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .green

        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closePressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        [centerLabel, closeButton, selectButton].forEach { item in
            item.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.addSubview(item)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            closeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 4),
            closeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -4),

            centerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 4),
            centerLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -4),
            centerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 4),

            selectButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -4),
            selectButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -4),
            selectButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 4)
        ])
        
    }
}
```

what i want to achieve is a white rounded rectangle with an arrow underneath in its center and an image inside the box.

I have tried using swiftui in this uikit however i failed many time.

if this was a regular swiftui i would have created a ZStack with a rounded rectangle and a custom shape as of the arrow.

and using kingfisher to fetch the image.

Comment: why not have the white rounded rectangle and the arrow could be simply a `UIImageView` below your rectangle, but of course you could draw that if that is a must...

Comment: Various ways to do that, from using a "stretchable" image to drawing it with `UIBezierPath`. I'd suggest searching (at Google or wherever) for `swift chat bubble`. Lots of examples - particularly with "bubble tails" - that would be a good starting point (and pretty easy to convert) to get the visual you are looking for.